# Message body changes after updating EmailMessage

Tags: exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

My target is to load an email message and if it's a new one mark it as read.

So here is what I am doing:

```
        EmailMessage email=EmailMessage.bind(service,itemId);
        email.load();
        email.setSubject(GeneralUtils.replaceSpecialCharacters(email.getSubject()));
        email.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(GeneralUtils.replaceSpecialCharacters(email.getBody().toString())));
        if(!email.getIsRead()){ 
          email.setIsRead(true);
          email.update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
        }
```

ISSUE: When reading the message body for first time (before marking the message as read)
I can read the message body correctly as follows:

```
This is message body
```

But after marking the message as read and update the message, when trying to load this email again, the message body loads as follows:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
This is message body
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise why I am getting this behavior, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by not setting the processed body, i **removed** the following line, and it works fine:

```
email.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(GeneralUtils.replaceSpecialCharacters(email.getBody().toString())));
```