# Send string content with special characters in email using EWS Java API

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I tried to send the 'String' content in email using EWS Java API:

```
<root>
 <tag1>text1</tag1>
 <tag2>text2</tag2>
</root>
```

The code I used is:

```
String msg = content given above;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(user, password);
service.setCredentials(credentials);
try {
    service.setUrl(new java.net.URI(exchangeURL));
    service.setTraceEnabled(true);
    EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
    message.setSubject(mail_sub);
    message.setFrom(fromaddress);
    message.setBody(new MessageBody(msg));
    message.getToRecipients().add("emailaddress");             
    message.send();
}
```

But I get the email content as:

> text 1 text 2

How do I solve this? I am using Exchange 2010 and EWS Java API 1.2.

Comment: `messsage.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(msg));` is how I saw it. Not much difference though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439926/message-body-changes-after-updating-emailmessage uses `GeneralUtils.replaceSpecialChars`

Comment: Hi, I tried getMessageBodyFromText(msg) also. But still get the same output...:(:(

Comment: GeneralUtils.replaceSpecialChars is a custom method....i tried replacing "<" with "&lt;" before posting into setBody. But still get the same output...

Comment: I generated an XML and parsed it as string. But i want all the tags to be sent as such. How do i get this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
message.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText(msg));
BodyType type = BodyType.Text;
message.getBody().setBodyType(type);
```

and that solved the problem...:):):)

Thanks.